# Google SipDemo application does not connect with UDP

Tags: android, sdk, sip, voip

I want to build an Android SIP client using Google SIP API. I installed SipDemo application to see if SIP API works as expected. But it didn't worked!

For testing purpose I used Linphone and sip2sip.info free VOIP servers but neither worked!
I changed the connection type to TCP, recompiled and it connected to Linphone.

But I need UDP.Does Google API support UDP?

This is where I downloaded the SIPDemo:
https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the RestComm Android SDK https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk or JAIN SIP for Android (bundle in Restcomm Android SDK).

Comment: I downloaded Restcomm SIP but could not compile it with Android Studio! I tried JAIN SIP and this error occurred: Error:(46, 81) error: incompatible types: HashMap<String,String> cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: Do I need something else beside this SDK?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-client-android-sdk-quick-start/ ?

Comment: I read seems that using Restcomm SIP SDK requires a Restcomm Server. Is this true? I need to use my app with a OpenSips server.

Comment: Do Jain Sip needs Restcomm Server too? Thanks

Comment: No. It doesn't Require RestComm, it works with any SIP Server that supports WebRTC ie potentially ICE for NAT Traversal in the future and DTLS-SRTP, etc for the media part